Java XSSFWorkbook giving wrong output of an excel
I have to read Data of an excel file.
I am using rest and there my output is fine but in the console of my IDE it looks really weird and I do not know how to change the format.
Here is a bit of the code:
private static XSSFWorkbook loadWorkbook(final String tableName) throws IOException {
  try (final var file =
      new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/tables/%s.xlsx".formatted(tableName))) {
    return new XSSFWorkbook(file);
  }
}

static List<List<String>> liefereEntgeltgruppen(final String tableName, final LocalDate date)
    throws IOException {

  final XSSFWorkbook wb = loadWorkbook(tableName);

  final List<List<String>> pastSheets = new ArrayList<>();

  final List<LocalDate> allSheetDates =
      StreamSupport.stream(wb.spliterator(), false)
          .map(LiefereEntgeltgruppen::getSheetDate)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .toList();

  final LocalDate closestPastDate =
      allSheetDates.stream()
          .filter(sheetDate -> !sheetDate.isAfter(date))
          .max(LocalDate::compareTo)
          .orElse(null);

  final List<List<String>> pastSheet = getSheetsByDate(wb, closestPastDate);
  if (pastSheet != null) {
    pastSheets.addAll(pastSheet);
  }

  final List<List<String>> futureSheets =
      StreamSupport.stream(wb.spliterator(), false)
          .filter(
              sheet -> {
                final LocalDate sheetDate = getSheetDate(sheet);
                return sheetDate != null && sheetDate.isAfter(date);
              })
          .map(LiefereEntgeltgruppen::liefereEntgeltgruppenFromSheet)
          .toList();

  wb.close();
  final List<List<String>> allSheets = new ArrayList<>();
  allSheets.addAll(pastSheets);
  allSheets.addAll(futureSheets);
  System.out.println(allSheets);
  return allSheets;
}

And here is the output in the console:
[[E�15�, E�15, E�14, E�13, E�12, E�11, E�10, E�9c, E�9b, E�9a, E�8, E�7, E�6, E�5, E�4, E�3, E�2�, E�2, EE1]]
Can anyone please help me to fix this problem?
I dont know what I have to change or what I have to try that my code will give me the right output.
